# How to find Fourier coefficients of a given function

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f(x)$ as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x)=0 & - \pi\leq x<0,\\
f(x)=1 & 0\leq x< \pi,
\end{cases}
$$
and set $f(x)=f(x+2\pi)$. How does one find the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$?

1) How can we show $f(x)$ is integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$?

2)By using the formula, I calculate that $c_n = 0$ when $n$ is even and $c_n = \frac{1}{in\pi}$ if $n$ odd. Is it correct?

Comment: why you post same question ? what is new here ?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364771/how-to-find-the-fourier-coefficient-of-this-function/1364778#1364778

Comment: Indeed, @Matthew, why post the same thing twice?

Answer (score 1):

1) $f$ is integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ because it is continuous almost everywhere and $[-\pi,\pi]$ has finite measure.

2) The calculation of $c_n$ can be done straight from the definition of the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$:
$$
\begin{align}c_n = \hat{f}(n) & := \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx\\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{0}0\cdot e^{-inx}dx + \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-inx}dx\\
& = -\frac{1}{2\pi in}(e^{-in\pi} - 1)\\
& = -\frac{1}{2\pi in}((-1)^{n\text{ mod }2}-1)
\end{align}
$$
So $c_n = 0$ for $n$ even and $c_n = \frac{1}{i\pi n} = -\frac{i}{\pi n}$ for $n$ odd, as you correctly calculated.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is integreble: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} 1 dx = \pi = 2\pi c_0$

$$f(x) = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{j=+\infty} c_j e^{ijx}$$

$$ c_j =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{ijx} dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{ijx} dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{ij}[e^{ij\pi} - 1] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{ij}[(-1)^j - 1] = \frac{i}{\pi j}\delta_{j, \text{odd}}$$

$$\Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=-\infty}^{j=+\infty} \frac{i}{\pi j} \delta_{j, \text{odd}} e^{ijx} = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{j=+\infty} \frac{i}{\pi j} (e^{ijx} - e^{-ijx}) $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2}{\pi }\sum_{j=1}^{j=+\infty} \frac{\text{sin}(jx)}{j} $$

Answer (score 0):

*For the second part*:

Firstly, the interval of the periodic function is $\boxed{L = 2\pi}$. The coefficients are calculated through the following formulas:

$a_0=\displaystyle \dfrac 1 L \cdot\int_{-L/2}^ {L/2} f(x) \, dx=\dfrac 1 L\cdot \bigg(\int_{-\pi}^{0}  0 \, dx +\int_{0}^\pi 1  \, dx\bigg)=\dfrac 12$

$a_n=\displaystyle \dfrac 2 L \cdot\int_{-L/2}^ {L/2}  f(x)\cdot \cos\left(\dfrac {2n\pi x} {L}\right) \, dx =\cdots = 0$

$b_n=\displaystyle \dfrac 2 L \cdot\int_{-L/2}^{L/2} f(x)\cdot \sin\left(\dfrac {2n\pi x} {L}\right) \, dx = \cdots=\dfrac {1+(-1)^{n+1}}{n\pi}=\begin{cases} 0, &\text{ $n>0$ is even}\\ \dfrac 2{n\pi},& \text{ $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$

The Fourier series of $f$ is:
$$ a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[ a_n \cdot \cos\left(\dfrac{2n\pi x}{L}\right) + b_n \cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{2n\pi x}{L}\right)\right]$$